# .NET MySql does "Using" closes the datareader?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysqldatareader

I used to close an open datareader using the try/catch/finally block:

```
 Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = Nothing
 Try
   dr = DBConnection.callReadingStoredProcedure("my_sp")

 Catch ex As Exception
   ' the caller will handle this
   Throw ex
 Finally
   If dr IsNot Nothing Then dr.Close()
 End Try
```

But I think it should be cleaner (and somewhat faster) to use the "Using" VB keyword:

```
Using dr As MySqlDataReader = DBConnection.callReadingStoredProcedure("my_sp")

End Using
'   dr is surely disposed, but is it closed?
```

Does the IDispose interface (required by Using) perform a Close on the DataReader?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object will be disposed. Yes, this closes the DataReader.

Comment: I believe it is inherited from IDataReader inheriting IDisposable. I'm fairly certain this is the behavior Microsoft would enforce.

Answer (score 0):

Reader will be closed, but this is not necessary for underlaying database connection because it is managed with ADO.NET connection pool.
Check this answer for more information: [C# MySqlConnection won't close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589340/c-sharp-mysqlconnection-wont-close/23244242#23244242)