# What does "pooling=false" in a MySQL connection string mean?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, connection-string

What does `pooling=false` in a .NET connection-string for a MySQL database mean?

This is the complete connection string:

```
return new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=myDataBase;USER=###;PASSWORD=***;POOLING=FALSE;");
```

Comment: Google [Connection-Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx), false means that you are not using it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [.net connection pooling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244126/net-connection-pooling)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When `pooling=false` the connection will not return to the pool when you call `SqlConnection.Close()`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx)

> When the value of this key is set to true, any newly created
>   connection will be added to the pool when closed by the application.
>   In a next attempt to open the same connection, that connection will be
>   drawn from the pool. Connections are considered the same if they have
>   the same connection string. Different connections have different
>   connection string

Answer (score 6):

Will the connection be part of a connection pool or not? This means that the connection be shared throughout the application instead of creating a new one every time you call open.

Note that for connection pooling to work, the connection string must be EXACTLY the same, meaning you cannot change a character in the string (even whitespace) and have pooling still work. Thus, the connection created by:

```
"SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=myDataBase;USER=###;PASSWORD=***;POOLING=FALSE;"
```

will not be shared with a connection created by:

```
" SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=myDataBase;USER=###;PASSWORD=***;POOLING=FALSE;"
```

because of the leading space.