# ServiceStack OrmLite: MySQL connection pool

Tags: mysql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I understand the topic is not new, I read a few posts but did not come to the answer ...

Each time the connection is opened for a very long time, but the idea was to use a connection pool, is not it?

As I understand it in MySQL you cannot specify a connection pool in the connection string.

How to do the right thing not to spend a lot of time opening the database connection?

Thanks!

```
    IDbConnectionFactory = connection = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(TeleportParams.DbConnectionStr, MySqlDialectProvider.Instance)

  ...

    void function1(){
       var db = connection.Open();
       db.Select("some request");
    }

    void function2(){
       var db = connection.Open();
       db.Select("some request");
    }

...

    function1();
    function2();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understand it in MySQL you cannot specify a connection pool in the connection string.

You can add `pooling=false` to the connection string to [disable Connection Pooling in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18337000/85785).